# Keeping several countdown timers using a queue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, queue

I need to keep up to an X (changeable amount) instances of countdown timers, each being added by the user, once a single one of them reaches 0 it calls for a function while the other counters keep counting.
for that purpose i tried to create a queue of them, but as it turns out, I can't change the value of an iteration variable in foreach:

```
public struct Debuff
{
    public float Timer;
    public int Stack;
    public int MaxStack;
    ...
}

public Debuff Poisoned;

public void CalcDamage(...)
{
    ...
    if (Poisoned.Stack < Poisoned.MaxStack)
    {
        Poisoned.Stack++;
        PoisonStacksTimer.Enqueue(Poisoned.Timer);
        InvokeRepeating("Poisoning", 0.1F, 1F);
    }
    else
    {
        PoisonStacksTimer.Dequeue();
        PoisonStacksTimer.Enqueue(Poisoned.Timer);
    }
}

public void Poisoning()
{
    foreach(float PTimer in PoisonStacksTimer)
    {
        TakeDamage(Poisoned.DmgTranslate);
        PTimer -= Time.deltaTime; // here lies at least one of the problems
        if (PTimer <= 0)
        {
            Poisoned.Stack--;
            PoisonStacksTimer.Dequeue();
            CancelInvoke("Poisoning");
        }
    }
}
```

is there any other way to use countdown timers in queue? or maybe a better way to achieve my objective?
this is my first time asking a question here so I hope I explained my problem clearly.

Comment: Do you add more stuff to the Queue timer while it is counting? Also, I think this is possible to do but may not be the best way to accomplish this. It would be better to explain why you're doing this and what this is used for for because you may end up using queue to do this only to find out it's be worst way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top my head, I'd use coroutines.

Every time you need to start a timer, you start an associated coroutine, so if you, at a specific moment, have for example 4 active timers, there'll be 4 coroutines.

In order to keep a reference to every single coroutine, use a `List<IEnumerator>`: every time a timer needs to be started, add the new `IEnumerator` reference and start the coroutine, so when a coroutine ends naturally or needs to be stopped, you can remove that reference from the list while keeping the other alive coroutines' references in the list.

Comment: Of course, you don't *need* coroutines. Having your own `ITimedThing` interface and storing a list (updating said list every `Update` cycle yourself) would work just as well.